# Retrieve XML Code by API with Automatic Approach

Tags: sql, xml, api, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Goal:
Retrieve a XML list from Internet, using API connection, and transfer the data into a sql server's table automatic using Scheduling tool with SQ server agent and its jobs.

Problem:
I have two questions:

1. What component in SSIS do I need to retrieve the XML file, using API connection?
2. Is it possible to use stored procedure, code that retrieve and transform the xml file and its data, to transfer it into a table? In This context, no usage of SSIS.

Information:
*The computers version is SQL 2008 R2 standard edition.

Answer (score 0):

1. If everything is straightforward, I would use Web Service Task. If not, use the Script Task and take care of API Connection in C# code. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) link.
2. Yes. to avoid SSIS, you need to create a CLR Stored Procedure. See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) link.

Comment: straightforward? What do you mean in this context?

Comment: Web Service Task has some prerequisites like WSDL. If that is not easily available/constructed I would go through Script Task.

Comment: Hello again. About the second point (avoid SSIS), it uses C#, I cannot view any pure SQL code to retrieve and convert the xml data into a table. I'm confused.

Comment: Everything in a CLR code will be done in Managed Code. You should create SQLCLRStoredProcedure project in Visual Studio. The following links are usefull: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zxsa8hkf(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I have a question about WSDL in relation to SSIS and its Web service task.  Where can I get the WSDL file inside of Webservice task? Maybe contact the provider and ask about WSDL file concept?

Comment: If there is a web service available try to type the web service address with /?wsdl Example:http://www.myServer.com/Service1.svc?wsdl. If not, try asking from the provider.